# Comparison Theorem for Matrix Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

I am looking for a matrix analogue of comparison theorem. Let's say we consider the two ODEs:
  $$\dot{X} = A(t)X(t), \ X(0) = \Xi$$ and $$\dot{Y} = B(t)Y(t), \ Y(0) = \Xi.$$

$A$ and $B$ are continuous (and perhaps smooth). I have two notions of order in hand. Do we have

1. If $A - B$ is positive definite for all $t$, can we say $X - Y$ is positive definite?
2. If each entry of $A$ is greater than or equal to $B$, i.e., $a_{ij} \geq b_{ij}$ for each $ij$ entry, can we say the same for the solution, i.e., does $x_{ij} \geq y_{ij}$?

I have read a lot on comparison theorem on matrix Riccati equation, but I can't find some helpful references on this simple type equation.

Comment: Regarding 2: Yes, it is a well-known result, however it is difficult to localize its formulation in the literature. I would argue as follows: the solution operator for a linear nonautonomous ODE is given as [ordered exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential), and all the operations occurring in the definition preserve the entrywise ordering.

Comment: So 1. Is not necessarily true?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Many thanks anyway. I believe 2. Is true, but just want to ha e some references to back me up